# Ext.Net :SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

when I leave empty DateField and get the value of this emty field via button click event,
i get the error like this
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

what I see while debugging ,it gets the value like this {01.01.0001 00:00:00},
what I wanna do is when It leave empty ,i get the Dbnull value or just null value thus I can insert to sqlserver this value.

```
  <ext:DateField ID="AlisTrh" runat="server" FieldLabel="Atrh" Type="Date" Format="dd-MM-yyyy"  Flex="1">
```

Comment: So set your SQL Table to `Allow Null` for that column.

Comment: It doesnt work,It already get the value something like this {01.01.0001 00:00:00},and as u see,it is not null

Comment: Have you actually tried setting the field nullable in SQL? maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406297/mvc-foolproof-validation-using-passonnull-nullable-or-01-01-0001-000000

Comment: please do not save `0` but `NULL` that should fix it, if the SQL-Table actually allows `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem like this

```
 public static DateTime? ConvertNullDate(this DateTime date)
        {
            return date != DateTime.MinValue ? date : (DateTime?)null;
        }
```