# Multiple MVC Foolproof Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, foolproof-validation

I am using [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) for my MVC 5 app.

I'm trying to say: EventPlanEnd is **not** required unless EventPlanStart is filled in. If it is, make sure **EventPlanEnd > EventPlanStart**. This doesn't seem to work...

```
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventPlanStart { get; set; }

 [RequiredIfTrue("EventPlanStart")]
 [GreaterThan("EventPlanStart")]
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventPlanEnd { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how I can do this with data annotations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Foolproof Validation using PassOnNull - Nullable or "01.01.0001 00:00:00"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406297/mvc-foolproof-validation-using-passonnull-nullable-or-01-01-0001-000000)

Comment: `[RequiredIfTrue]` is only applicable if the other property is a `bool`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `RequiredIfNot` instead of `RequiredIfTrue` which takes a `boolean`. This is an untested code:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventPlanStart { get; set; }

[RequiredIfNot("EventPlanStart", null)]
[GreaterThan("EventPlanStart")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventPlanEnd { get; set; }
```